# UIView Orientation change in Swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I'm developing an app to display a binary tree.

Each node will be displayed as a subview programatically generated from the ViewController - I run the following from viewDidLayoutSubviews().

```
    let theView = BinaryTreeView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: width, height: 100))
    //  let theView = BinaryTreeView(s: "I'm testing")
    theView.backgroundColor = .white
    theView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target:theView, action:#selector(BinaryTreeView.changeScale(recognizer:))))
    self.view.addSubview(theView)
    theView.eyesOpen = false


    let secondView = BinaryTreeView(frame: CGRect(x: width/2, y: 150, width: width/2, height: 100))
    //  let theView = BinaryTreeView(s: "I'm testing")
    secondView.backgroundColor = .white
    secondView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target:secondView, action:#selector(BinaryTreeView.changeScale(recognizer:))))
    self.view.addSubview(secondView)


    let thirdView = BinaryTreeView(frame: CGRect(x: (width/2)+width/4, y: 250, width: width/4, height: 100))
    //  let theView = BinaryTreeView(s: "I'm testing")
    thirdView.backgroundColor = .white
    thirdView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target:thirdView, action:#selector(BinaryTreeView.changeScale(recognizer:))))
    self.view.addSubview(thirdView)
```

The issue is that on orientation change the views repeat each other (above there are three nodes, on orientation change 4 might display.

I looked through Stack and Within my subclassed UIView I added:

```
self.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.redraw
```

Within the programatic Subview but the same happens.

Don't worry - I'm going to generate my nodes in a loop later (I'm trying to understand how layout works). Incidentally I found the same happened using a UICollectionView so I seem to be doing something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the "target:" to the controller (to self) for all three. Your controller will respond to gestures, not the views themselves. The target will be the same in all three cases.

```
secondView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target:secondView, action:#selector(BinaryTreeView.changeScale)))
    self.view.addSubview(secondView)
```

becomes

```
 secondView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(BinaryTreeView.changeScale)))
    self.view.addSubview(secondView)
```

Comment: Thanks - but the gestures are working fine. The question is about orientation change and objects not regenerating properly.

Comment: You said you were getting extra objects on orientation change. That's because you've chained your recognizers by chaining your targets. Did you try replacing the target to self for all 3? Did the behavior change?

Comment: If I make the change to self, and then click on an object I get a crash. Unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Comment: That's because your selector is malformed. Remove "(recognizer:)" I assume you're using swift 3.

Comment: Still the same (It's a different selector):        theView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(BinaryTreeView.returnHead)))